# TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to createsuper user
when I entered email and password I got this error

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ZAKARIA/Desktop/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 232, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first_name' and 'last_name'
```

my class managers

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManger(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not first_name or last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first and last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email,password, first_name, last_name):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(user.password)
        #user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        #user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

models

```
import datetime
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from .managers import UserManger

GENDER_MALE = "m"
GENDER_FEMALE = "f"
OTHER = "o"

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (GENDER_MALE, "Male"),
    (GENDER_FEMALE, "Female"),
    (OTHER, "Other"),
)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/users', null=True, verbose_name="")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #credits =models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    linkedin_token = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManger()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name' , 'last_name']
    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%S %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, prem, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        return True

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        return True
    ''''
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff"
        return self.is_admin'''
    
    """@property
    def is_out_of_credits(self):
        "Is the user out of credits"
        return self.credits > 0
    @property
    def has_sufficient_credits(self,cost):
        return self.credits - cost >= 0
        """
    @property
    def linkedin_signed_in(self):
        return bool(self.linkedin_token) and self.expiry_date > timezone.now()
```

I have been seeing a lot of questions similar to this but i still don't understand the answers given, some say add positional arguements, I don't quite understand

> can any one help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: try to change definition to `def create_superuser(self, email, password,**kwargs)` and use it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you have some extra fields in the UserModel that are not passing accurately in the `create_superuser`.

Try `**extra_fields` arg instead of passing first_name, last_name separately, as the docs about [Manager methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods) suggest,

> The extra_fields keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s
> **init** method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom user model.

So, modify your `UserManger` class according to this and then this will rectify the problem.

Modified Code:

```
class UserManger(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model"""

    def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Now you can set `first_name`, `last_name`, as `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in the `UserModel`, like this.

```
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name' , 'last_name']
```

For detailed information on `BaseUserManager`, you can also check [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager)

Edit:
After seeing your UserModel, this would be better the use AbstractUser instead of AbstractBaseUser, AbstractUser will carry all the fields that a default Django User has. So you don't have to define the fields like first_name, last_name, is_staff or etc...

That is how you can modify it

```
# import
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Model 
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None # as you are using email as username
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/users', null=True, verbose_name="")
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #credits =models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    linkedin_token = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManger()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name' , 'last_name'] 
    # Do anything else here
```

Comment: And now I got this error   ```  TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'  ```

Comment: Can u please update the question with UserModel

Comment: Replace AbstractBaseUser with AbstractUser,

Comment: Or activate is_staff

Comment: Let me modify the model for you and will update the answer

Comment: @ZakariaZhlat Hey check the edited Anwer.

Answer (score 0):

missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'eml'
If you face this error and you use class based view so please remove your self and other parameter which is define in function. Your function need only request as parameter run properly. I am just sharing my experience because I have lost my lot of time behind this error.

> def delete(self, request, eml):
> print(request.GET.get('d_id'))
> return HttpResponse('delete')

It's working fine for me.

> ```
> def delete(request):
>  print(request.GET.get('d_id'))
>  return HttpResponse('delete')
> ```

If you use class based view even then remove self parameter from method. I hope it will help you.